# Having an issue with updating state variable in context in react app

Tags: reactjs, rest, state

I have been building a Laravel and React app and I had encountered something very embarassing.
The state variable context value is not changing with setState function. The code is following.

```js
const ApiProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  const [repNumbers, setRepNumbers] = React.useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {

    }
    fetchData()

    return () => {
      setData({})
    }
  }, [])

  return <ApiContext.Provider value = {
      {
        repData: data,
        loading,
        repNumbers, //this is the state variable
        setRepNumbers //this is the setState function 
      }
    } > {
      children
    } <
    /ApiContext.Provider>
}
```

In the consumming component

```
const { repData, repNumbers, setRepNumbers } = React.useContext(ApiContext)
const [pageLoading, setPageLoading] = React.useState(true) 

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        setPageLoading(true)
        await Axios({

        })
            .then((res) => {                    
                setRepNumbers({...repNumbers, [id]: res.data })
                setPageLoading(false)
                return false
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return {}
            })


        return false
    }
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

If there are 2 consuming components, there should be 2 api calls and the repNumbers state should be mutated 2 times and add 2 id data but it only contains one id and if other call resolves, it replace the former id.

So how can I get both ids in repNumbers state?

Answer (score 0):

This: ***...but it only contains one id and if other call resolves, it replace the former id.***

Assuming React 18 from your question. If so, React "*Batches*" updates. So although two updates were made, only the very last one was recorded.

This is dicussed [in this blog post](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21).

You can consider [`flushSync()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/flushSync)

You might also consider refactoring your code to avoid the situation in the first place.